# What is the difference between "Force Start" and "Start" in BitTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent

My BitTorrent download has been stuck at 99.8% for five hours. The bar is green so I have no idea what's going on.

If I pause it and "Force Start" it again there is still no progress.

1. What's the difference between "Start" and "Force Start"?
2. What's the difference between "Pause" and "Stop"?

Comment: And which software are you using?

Comment: @slhck i downloaded it from here http://www.bittorrent.com/downloads

Comment: What is the availability of your file?  I suspect that nobody has a full copy, which is why yours is stuck at 99.8%.

Comment: @Brad wow do you mean the seed is the availability of my file? Because it is currently **0 (0)**. how do i *switch area* to search for peers with the file?

Comment: @Brad my peers show **12 (34)** do you happen to know if i have 12 peers or 34 peers?

Comment: @Pacerier, No, somewhere there it should list file availability.  An availability of 2 means that there are 2 full copies of the torrent available.  I suspect yours says 0.998, which means that none of the peers currently have a full copy.

Comment: @Brad oh my. what can be done to remedy this situation? otherwise everyone will be stuck at 99.98 eventually and never get 100!

Comment: @Pacerier, someone would have to seed the full copy...

Comment: @Brad so you are saying i need to have my computer on until that person decides to seed? is there something else I can do like connect to a different group of peers or restart my internet or smt?

Comment: welcome to peer-to-peer :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- **Force start** will force a download even if you have more downloads going then you enabled at once.  For example, if you set a max download limit of 3 torrents, and have 5 all set to "Start", only 3 will run at once.  However, if you force-start one of them, then 4 will run.
- **Pause** doesn't kill your connections, it just (severely) limits your transfer speed.  It keeps the connection open between peers/seeders (and the tracker), so you can (almost) instantly resume downloading.
- **Stop** closes your connection between you, any peers/seeders, and the tracker.

Comment: It also means that if you have automatic stop-after-seeding-some-percentage configured, then it will continue seeding regardless of this setting.

Comment: ok so you are saying if i have unlimited max downloads, Force Start and Start is never going to be any different from the other (and the download speed will not be affected whatsoever)?

Comment: Force start will also start a torrent that is idle (queued) due to no peers.

Comment: Note that the distinction between pause and stop depends on your client. For example in qBittorent, pause closes connections too.