# What does the "force resume" feature of BitTorrent clients actually do?

Tags: bittorrent

In every BitTorrent client I've ever used, there are two features: "resume" and "force resume". If "resume" doesn't work, one can "force resume", which often actually works. As if you are digitally "kicking" the torrent with your foot to make it start/continue from being stalled/stuck.

This is satisfying when it works, but what exactly does it do? And if it can do this, why doesn't the normal "resume" feature do whatever the "force resume" one does? Or even automatically, without any requirement for the user to be there and manually intervene?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "Force Start" and "Start" in BitTorrent?](https://superuser.com/questions/321527/what-is-the-difference-between-force-start-and-start-in-bittorrent)

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two options depends on your seeding rules.

A typical example might be
"up to 8 torrents total active with up to three of those being downloads".
So if you have a large number of torrents, not all of them will be active
when the limit specified by the rule is exceeded.
Inactive torrents may have their status indicated as "Queued".

The torrents that are inactive will wait for an active torrent
to terminate so they can start.
The "force resume" command will force an inactive torrent to become active,
so exceeding the limit.

The command "resume" is for use when some torrent(s) is suspended
manually by yourself. These torrents stay inactive until you use the
"resume" command. Then they can wait for an active slot to become available,
so if the limit was not exceeded they will start working immediately.

Even when active, a torrent may not do much if it's searching for
sources on the internet, or if it is waiting for some source(s) to
agree to the connection.

Answer (score 1):

#### What exactly does Force Resume do?

In qBittorrent:

> It keeps the connection open between peers/seeders (and the tracker), so you can (almost) instantly resume downloading. Stop closes your connection between you, any peers/seeders, and the tracker.

Source: [Question: Can Qbittorrent Upload Files From Computer - SovereignValley](https://www.sovereignvalley.com/can-qbittorrent-upload-files-from-computer/)

Other clients may also have this option ([Deluge](https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/) doesn't)

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a description for a “resume” function, but instead for “pause”.